# Design clarification: Getting Oracle table inserts in RabbitMQ

Tags: java, oracle, spring-boot, rabbitmq, spring-integration

I have created a spring boot + websocket + stomp application with rabbitmq configured. Now, I need to get updates from oracle table upon a table INSERT (which is done by external service) in the queue, so that I could process it and send it back it to the exchange which the broker will send to the client application

I would like to know if it is possible to get the table inserts in the rabbitmq queue, so that I could write a queue listener and get the data to be processed? Can this be done via rabbitmq configuration, if yes, could you please share any references so that I could dig deep? I could not find any references online though.

Now if it is not possible to somehow configure oracle datasource in rabbitmq, please let me know if there are any other ways I could achieve it.

Comment: Hi @continuousLearner, were you successful at doing this?